# XML output from Neo4j cypher query

Tags: xml, rest, neo4j, cypher

Is it possible to get `xml` formatted results from a cypher query in `neo4j` using the `REST API`?
With `curl`, I tried the following `-H 'Content-type:text/xml'` but it still returns `json` formatted data.

Is there a way to return `xml` formatted data instead?

Thanks in advance, Pierre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you could write a [server plugin](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/server-plugins.html) that forms valid XML conformant with some graph representation format and then server will just wrap it into JSON where you will extract it from later, If simple server plugin couldn't do that, you could try more raw form of plugins - [unmanaged extensions](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/server-unmanaged-extensions.html).

Besides that, I don't know any ways. Well, maybe convert already received JSON to XML, but that'll require further looks into from you.